# VCenter 5.0 Server shows error on Hardware Status for hosts (port 8443)

Tags: port, vmware-vcenter

I have the following:

- vCenter 5.0.0 build 755629

The problem:

In the plug-in manager:

**vCenter Hardware Status**

```
VMware, Inc.
5.0
Disabled
Displays the hardware 
status of hosts (CIM 
monitoring)
The following error occured while downloading the 
script plugin from https://192.168.1.1:8443/cim-ui
/scriptConfig.xml: 
The client could not send a complete request to 
the server. (The underlying connection was closed
: An unexpected error occurred on a send.)
```

**vCenter Service Status**

```
VMware, Inc.
5.0
Disabled
Displays the health status 
of vCenter services
The following error occured while downloading the 
script plugin from https://192.168.1.1:8443/health
-ui/scriptConfig.xml: 
The client could not send a complete request to 
the server. (The underlying connection was closed
: An unexpected error occurred on a send.)
```

**What I have tried**

- Read many article online regarding this matter.
- Enabled - Secure Socket Tunneling Protocol Service
- I can access the URLs located above with only **http**, thus there must be an issue with SSL, I am guessing here.

**Side notes:**

- We have no plans to update to vCenter 5.1 as of yet.
- I have been looking for 2 days for a solution so far.

Does anyone know of any solution for this please?

Comment: @ewwhite, thanks. I gave that ago, first article I read on serverfault. That one did not work.

Answer (score 1):

- Did you try connecting to the hosts directly to view hardware status?
- What type of hosts do you have?
- Have you refreshed your browser?
- Have you rebooted vCenter?
- What is 192.168.1.1? Is it a host or a vCenter?

You should be able to browse to those URLs via https: `https://172.16.2.8:8443/cim-ui/scriptConfig.xml`

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<scriptConfiguration version="1.0">
<key>com.vmware.vim.cimmonitor.gwt</key>
<description>Hardware Status (CIM Service)</description>
<useInternalSSLProxy>true</useInternalSSLProxy>
<extension parent="InventoryView.HostSystem">
<title locale="de">Hardwarestatus</title>
<title locale="fr">État du matériel</title>
<title locale="ja">ハードウェアのステータス</title>
<title locale="ko">하드웨어 상태</title>
<title locale="zh-CN">硬件状态</title>
<title locale="en">Hardware Status</title>
<url>https://*:8443/cim-ui/index.html</url>
</extension>
</scriptConfiguration>
```

Comment: Did you try connecting to the hosts directly to view hardware status? Yes, works perfectly, Health Status is all good.
What type of hosts do you have? Fujitsu BX620, compatible with vmware 5.0.0
Have you refreshed your browser? Many times. 
Have you rebooted vCenter? Yes I have. 
What is 192.168.1.1? Is it a host or a vCenter? 192.168.1.1 is vCenter. I can see the file ONLY on `http://192.168.1.1:8443/cim-ui
/scriptConfig.xml` not https.